# One word for upgrade and downgrade (or similar)?

Tags: single-word-requests, software

As a software developer, I am working on a project with service tiers, such that a user may opt to switch their current subscription to a tier above or below it. A single module handles both "upgrade" and "downgrade" operations. What would be the appropriate name for this module (as seen on a user interface)?

My Google searches have found a couple of options, the closest one pointing me to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119608/combine-upgrade-and-downgrade).
I do not think "regrade" is particularly appropriate for this use case.

As used in a menu on the user interface, it would be something like:

- Edit Profile
- [Word] Account
- Delete Account

If possible, I would ask that it be one word.

EDIT: A word or brief phrase that basically means "change payment plan" is acceptable.

Comment: [***Versioning**](https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/versioning) is the creation and management of multiple releases of a product.*

Comment: Word of warning: We don't do software names; they are [explicitly off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The reason for that is you could call your module "modSusan" and it would work just as well. Obviously that wouldn't do for a user-visible menu entry, so that part of your question is on-topic.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why "**Change** payment plan" is unsuitable.

Comment: - or indeed, ***Change** version*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach noted, and I will edit that out. 
I need a word that I can use to describe the operation being carried out on the account/payment plan, as succinctly as possible.
Change seems a little wide, but I will keep it in reserve.

Comment: Edit profile. Change plan. Delete account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best service-level applications I've encountered is HP Instant Ink for Hewlett Packard wireless printers. The module that allows a subscriber to upgrade or downgrade their plan is called *My Plan*. When you click on *My Plan*, you go to a page that provides the options available (Occasional Printing, Moderate Printing, Frequent Printing, Heavy Printing, and Business Printing), with an obvious checkmark denoting your current plan, e.g., Frequent Printing. All you need to do to upgrade or downgrade your plan is click on another plan. So, one possibility would be for you to call the upgrade/downgrade module *My Plan* and by virtue of intuitive page design avoid altogether the need for a phrase meaning "change payment plan".

Comment: I will accept this, because it provided a possible solution and got me thinking as well.

Comment: @PeterLenjo Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A menu item selection that said "Service-Level Selection" would make sense. Businesses are used to the term SLA "Service-Level agreements."

Comment: And what operation is being carried out on this SLA when a user opts to go for a different, or "upper"/"lower" class of services?

Comment: No operation is necessary, create one SLA that explains these various service level choices clearly along with other items you want to include with respect to the level of service your client can expect from you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a software as a service (SAAS) application, you could call your option "Subscription" or "Subscription Level".